# Python zip the first element of a list with the rest of elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
mylist = [(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3)]
```

i wish to find a code saving method to zip the first element `mylist[0]` with the rest of the list element `mylist[1:]` in order to get a new list as:

```
[((0,0,0),(1,1,1)),((0,0,0),(2,2,2)),((0,0,0),(3,3,3))]
```

Comment: Not sure why you would *want* to do that.

Answer (score 9):

Using `zip`:

```
>>> mylist = [(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3)]
>>> zip([mylist[0]]*(len(mylist)-1), mylist[1:])
[((0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)), ((0, 0, 0), (2, 2, 2)), ((0, 0, 0), (3, 3, 3))]
```

A list comprehension is even simpler:

```
>>> [ (mylist[0], sublist) for sublist in mylist[1:] ]
[((0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)), ((0, 0, 0), (2, 2, 2)), ((0, 0, 0), (3, 3, 3))]
```

Comment: I checked the edit history to ensure you didn't snipe iCodez for extra credit. You didn't. +1

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that `zip` is necessary here.  A [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will work fine:

```
>>> mylist = [(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3)]
>>> [(mylist[0], x) for x in mylist[1:]]
[((0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)), ((0, 0, 0), (2, 2, 2)), ((0, 0, 0), (3, 3, 3))]
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using map:

```
map(lambda x:(mylist[0],x),mylist[1:])
```

Output:

```
[((0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)), ((0, 0, 0), (2, 2, 2)), ((0, 0, 0), (3, 3, 3))]
```

Comment: +1 but map is just half of a comprehension, with an awkward lambda.